# How to make two dataframes one with values and another with boolean into one dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have two dataframes like:

dataframe1 would be

```
            A     B     C     D     E
values1  0.25  0.33  0.12  0.22  0.08
values2  0.20  0.50  0.89  0.65  0.75
```

and dataframe2 would be

```
              A     B     C      D     E
boolean1   True False  True  False  True
boolean2  False False  True   True  True
```

and want a result with one dataframe:

```
      A  B     C     D     E
1  0.25  0  0.12     0  0.08  
2     0  0  0.89  0.65  0.78
```

So if it is True in dataframe2 just bring the value from the dataframe1 and if it is False then replace with 0. How can I do this?

Comment: You have a typo, the last cell value in the expected result should be `0.75`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
df1 = df1.where(df2.values, 0)
# or
df1 = df1.mask(~df2.values, 0)
```

```
print(df1)

            A    B     C     D     E
values1  0.25  0.0  0.12  0.00  0.08
values2  0.00  0.0  0.89  0.65  0.75
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to just multiply the values in the dataframe, then create the dataframe out of it.

```py
>>> out = pd.DataFrame(df1.values * df2.values, columns=df1.columns)
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
      A    B     C     D     E
0  0.25  0.0  0.12  0.00  0.08
1  0.00  0.0  0.89  0.65  0.75
```

Or you can just multiply the dataframes dropping the indices:

```py
>>> df1.reset_index(drop=True)*df2.reset_index(drop=True)

      A    B     C     D     E
0  0.25  0.0  0.12  0.00  0.08
1  0.00  0.0  0.89  0.65  0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) if its guaranteed that both dataframe will always be of same shape.

##### creating the data

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['values1', '0.25', '0.33', '0.12', '0.22', '0.08'], ['values2', '0.20', '0.50', '0.89', '0.65', '0.75']], columns = ['index', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']).set_index('index')

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['boolean1', True, False,  True,  False,  True], ['boolean2',  False, False,  True,   True,  True]], columns = ['index', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']).set_index('index')
```

##### Mask

```
df1.mask(~df2.values, 0)
```

##### Output

This gives us

```
            A  B     C     D     E
index                             
values1  0.25  0  0.12     0  0.08
values2     0  0  0.89  0.65  0.75
```